# Tailwind and NextJS missing colors when compiled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

## Edit

### Added simplified repo link to bottom of post to reproduce issue.

I have got a JSON file which builds up my website, here is a snippet of it:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "home",
    "path": [
      ""
    ],
    "name": "Home",
    "showInNav": true,
    "isDynamic": false,
    "components": [
      {
        "id": "promotion-1",
        "name": "PromotionImage",
        "theme": "default",
        "props": {
          "image": {
            "path": "",
            "alt": "Alt text here",
            "position": "right"
          },
          "classes": {
            "wrapper": {
              "classes": "bg-zinc-900"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This gets build up like so:

```js
// [...path].tsx

import getPagePaths from '../services/getPagePaths';
import getPageProps from '../services/getPageProps'; // Import the above JSON file here. 

import Looper from '@lib/core/components/Looper';

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = await getPagePaths();

    return {
        paths: paths.map((path) => ({ params: { path } })),
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const page = await getPageProps(params.path);

    return { props: { ...page, components: page.components || [] } };
}

const Page = ({ components }): JSX.Element => {
    return <Looper components={components} />;
};

export default Page;
```

```js
// Looper.tsx

const Looper = ({ components }): JSX.Element => {
    if (!components || !components.length) return null;

    return components.map((component) => {
        const Component = require(`@lib/themes/${component.theme}/components/${component.name}`).default;

        return !Component ? null : <Component key={component.id} {...component.props} />;
    });
};

export default Looper;
```

```
// PromotionImage.tsx

const PromotionImage = ({ classes, image, components }: PromotionProps): JSX.Element => {
    const wrapperClasses = ['px-0 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 pt-0 sm:pt-[60px] py-[40px] sm:py-[60px] md:py-[80px]', classes?.wrapper || ''].join(' ').trim();

    return (
        <section className={wrapperClasses}>
    ...
```

So it's simple, we import the json file, loop through the items and require the component's with the path we build up, then check to see if there is any classes in this JSON object and merge them.

So for example the `bg-zinc-900` class should be getting applied to the `wrapper`. However this is not the case, but if I briefly put that class within the component itself and then remove it, the class gets applied.

It feels like when ever tailwind is treeshaken this class isn't being seen if imported from the JSON, any ideas?

I have added the component to the config too, so tailwind will see the component.

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    content: ['./lib/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
};
```

## Edit:

I have created a simplified project to [show the issue here](https://github.com/martynball/test-next-project).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run `next dev`.
2. You will see `Testing` on the page, with a red colour. Within `data/classes.json` you can see there is also `bg-zinc-900`.
3. Add that class to the first array item in `wrapper` on `index.js`, background will be applied, remove it, will still be there.

Comment: Did you add the JSON file to the content configuration option? (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#content) Tailwind probably doesn't know that the color class is being used and strips it out.

Comment: @Joren This JSON file isn't in a format that tailwind would understand though.

Comment: @Joren See update, added a simplified repo to post to reproduce error.

Comment: @Joren turns out this way the issue... -_- I didn't think they would work due to being JSON file formatted nothing like a tailwind config, i guess it just looks for classes...